# Can I password protect a Sinatra app from the routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, sinatra

I am mounting a Sinatra app in my routes. I'd like to provide http basic auth to it. Can I do it from the routes file?

```
mount My::App, :at => "/mysin"
```

I know I could check the request for the auth header, but I don't know how to provide the auth dialog to the user. Normally, from a controller, I'd do `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic`, but since I'm not in the context of a controller, this does not work. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
My::App.use(Rack::Auth::Basic) do |username, password|
  username == 'some_user' && password == 'some_password'
end 
mount My::App, :at => "/path"
```